# Some RewriteRules not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've added this code in my .htaccess, but only the second RewriteRule is working and I can't figure out why.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#
RewriteRule ^album/(.+)$ /album?folder1=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^gara/(.+)$ /gara?ID_manifestazione=$1 [L]
#
</IfModule>
```

The rest of the .htaccess is

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-   postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Not working means that if i insert a URL like "mysite.com/album/variable" it gives me a 404 error.
Moreover I tested the .htacces here (http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it answer with the right URL.

/album is not a folder, is a Wordpress rewritten URL. Both gara and album are Wordpress pages, and /gara and /album are their permalinks.

Any clues?

Comment: What does work or work not mean exactly? Most likely, there's a script corresponding to gara, but not for album.

Comment: Not working means that if i insert a URL like "mysite.com/album/variable" it gives me a 404 error.
The script exist. Moreover I tested the .htacces here (http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it answer with the right URL

Comment: Is there a .htaccess under `/album/` folder also?

Comment: album is not a folder, is a Wordpress rewritten URL

Comment: And how does this Wordpress rewrite rule look like?

Comment: Actually I don't know, because it's somewere in the Wordpress files, but "gara" has the same RewriteRule, so the problem insn't there either.
I've updated the answer with the full .htaccess now, if can be helpful

Comment: I guess, the wordpress permalink doesn't work, means isn't setup or the target doesn't exist. Another reason for the problem might be the target script is called properly (which means the rule is working), but it sends the 404 error.

Comment: But if I use a rule non rewrited ( ../album?folder1var=value ), the page loads correctly

Comment: Ok, but `folder1var` is different from `folder1`.

Comment: You're right, but it's a typo. The correct url is  ../album?folder1=value